# How to overwrite the existing files using hadoop fs -copyToLocal command

Tags: hadoop

Is there any way we can overwrite existing files, while coping from `HDFS` using:

```
hadoop fs -copyToLocal <HDFS PATH> <local path>
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you could easily knock together a little script surely to do this for you if it that much of an issue? Combining this with an existence check and `rm` should suffice.

Comment: You should move this into the answers section!

Answer (score 49):

```
fs -copyFromLocal -f $LOCAL_MOUNT_SRC_PATH/yourfilename.txt your_hdfs_file-path
```

So `-f` option does the trick for you.

It also works for `-copyToLocal` as well.

Comment: Oh yeah well did you know -f doesn't work for copyToLocal?

Comment: -f does not work with copyToLocal. Check documentation: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#copyToLocal

Answer (score 13):

You can first delete, then write.

`hadoop fs -rmr <path>` removes everything under given path in hdfs including the path itself

`rm -rf <path>` removes in local file system.

Make sure that there is no other file in the directory.

Comment: "hadoop fs -rmr <path>" this command not only removes files under this path, but also removes this directory. If you just want to remove files not directory, you should use "hadoop fs -rm <path>/*"

Comment: Do you think it is not gonna give exception when he tries to run the same command after `hadoop fs -rm <path>/*`?

Comment: in fact, if you do that, it gives warn, but not exception.

Comment: Try and tell it again

Comment: Btw, rmr has been deprecated; use rm -r instead.

Comment: Apart that rmr has been deprecated in favour of rm -r, but I think it's not a good practice to delete all the content of a dir when, maybe, only one file will be overwritten. Better the answer from Arijit that seems to do the trick in the correct way.

Answer (score 7):

I used the command below and it helped:

```
hadoop fs -put -f <<local path>> <<hdfs>>
```

but from put docs:

> Copy single src, or multiple srcs from local file system to the
>   destination file system.

Answer (score 5):

Force option is not there for either of the commands (`get` /`copytolocal`).

Below are three options:

1. Remove the file on localmachine with [rm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rm_%28Unix%29) command and use `copyToLocal/get`.
2. Rename your local file to new name so that you can have the file with same name as on cluster. use [mv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mv) command for that and use `get/copyTolocal` command.
3. Rename the file there on the cluster itself and use copytolocal

   ```
   hadoop fs -mv [oldpath] [newpath]
   hadoop fs -copytolocal [newpath] .
   ```

Answer (score 5):

`-f` option did the trick

example:

```
bin>hdfs dfs -put -f D:\DEV\hadoopsampledata\mydata.json /input
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead).

Comment: OP is for `copyToLocal`, not for local to HDFS.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with distcp with -update . Main advantage is  it will be update the target only when there is change in the file.

hadoop distcp -update  file://source hdfs://namenode/target

```
hadoop distcp -update  file:///home/hduser/pigSample/labfiles/SampleData/books.csv  hdfs://10.184.37.158:9000/yesB
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try this :

```
bin/hadoop fs -rm /path_of_the_file | grep "0" | bin/hadoop fs -put ~/input_path /output_path
```

Answer (score -3):

The -f work me.

> hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal -f [LOCALFILEPATH] [HDFSFILEPAHT]