# hdfs dfs -put with overwrite?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am using

```
hdfs dfs -put myfile mypath
```

and for some files I get

```
put: 'myfile': File Exists
```

- does that mean there is a file with the same name or does that mean the same exact file (size, content) is already there?
- how can I specify an -overwrite option here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 66, accepted):

`put: 'myfile': File Exists`

Means,the file named "myfile"  already exists in hdfs. You cannot have multiple files of the same name in hdfs

You can overwrite it using `hadoop fs -put -f /path_to_local /path_to_hdfs`

Comment: thanks! very helpful. i does put checks whether the transfer went through correctly? lets say i start hdfs put and the I close my console. does hdfs has now some corrupted file?

Comment: To check whether copied file is correct (with respect to size) or not, you can use hdfs dfs -ls /filename. It will show the file size in bytes, along with other info. @ Noobie

Comment: So `hdfs dfs -put -f input output` doesn't work? I've found sources that says it does

Comment: The accepted answer is wrong. I just tested hdfs dfs -put -f and it works perfectly.

Comment: In my case, I got an error `java.io.IOException: File -f does not exist.`

Answer (score 42):

You can overwrite your file in hdfs using -f command.For example

```
hadoop fs -put -f <localfile> <hdfsDir>
```

OR

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal -f <localfile> <hdfsDir>
```

It worked fine for me. However -f command won't work in case of get or copyToLocal command. [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16437548/how-to-overwrite-the-existing-files-using-hadoop-fs-copytolocal-command)

Answer (score 5):

1. A file with the same name exists at the location you're trying to write to.
2. You can overwrite by specifying the -f flag.

Comment: AFAIK, we cannot overwrite the files present in hdfs, and that is why hadoop is known for "write once read multiple" property. Am I wrong??

Comment: @user007, You can delete files and create a new file with the same name, overwrite. And in some cases you can append data at the end of the file but only at the end. Append is only available in hadoop version that include it and it is required for HBase and other framworks.

Answer (score 2):

Just updates to this answer, in Hadoop 3.X the command a bit different

```
hdfs dfs -put -f /local/to/path hdfs://localhost:9870/users/XXX/folder/folder2
```

Comment: For additions like that preferably edit the accepted answer or leave a comment next time :)